# After data-login_uri redirection from GSI script that redirect on POST backend endpoint, how to redirect to frontend with token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-oauth, google-client-login

My stack on this project is Reactjs frontend + Asp.net core backend

I have integrated in my React frontend the google button API to allow user to logged with their google account. And in this script , there is a parameter *data-login_uri* that's trigger after the user logged-in via google window and redirect to my ASP.NET CORE backend endpoint.

On this endpoint, that is a controller endpoint, Google send the tokenid that will be used to verify the authenticity of the user.

The problem is that from this endpoint , i want to redirect to another endpoint that `/api/login` that is my backend endpoint to just `/login`.

That is the GSI script integrated on my **login.jsx** page.

```html
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="XXX"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="https://localhost:44462/api/login"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div className="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     caca-zizi="sdfsdf"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

data-login_uri make the redirection to my ASP.Net core controller.

And here , my ASP.NET controller that receivee that tokenid from google, treat it and send back a generated token for the user

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/")]
public class GoogleAuthController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<StatusCodeResult> ReturnFromApi()
    {
        var tokenid  = HttpContext.Request.Form["credential"];
        GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload =  await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(tokenid);
        if (!payload.Audience.Equals(_config["ClientId"]))
               return BadRequest();
        ...

         return Ok(token);
     }
}
```

But with this, the return OK is still on the "/api/login" URL , so on my backend and if i use redirect("/login") i have find no method to add and object with the redirect method.

Comment: Same issue here, have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi, finally i left behind the idea of managing the token from backend and make it in front end.
explication  here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287431/14111113

Answer (score 0):

After 2 month , i think that i figure out why this wasn't possible.

React/Angular/Vue.js and other modern web framework are client-side rendering framework. That means web page rendering is managed by the browser.

> In Client-side rendering framework, the server part is an API that delivers JSON or XML to the client, and
> isn’t involved in HTML rendering.

And the script **is not making an api call** to the backend but **redirects us to the API backend url** that cannot manage web page for these framework, so we are stuck.

My personal opinion is that the GSI POST redirection is for server-side rendering framework that can manage webpage from the server. *(for example Blazor - ASP.NET)*

So unfortunately, i think that we have to manage token directely from the browser (until google develop another solution).

[Differences server and client side rendering](https://www.site24x7.com/learn/web-rendering-techniques.html)